# Flutter web - how to detect mouse hover over a widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

For my Flutter web app, how can I detect when the mouse hovers over a container widget?

Comment: check this answer please its works on web  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75182060/6813907

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `Container` widget with `MouseRegion` and use its `onHover` method. For further information about `MouseRegion` check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html).